# Simply being a bad worker or just in the wrong position?

Tags: resume, career-development, work-experience

To put it straight: I think I'm a mediocre (java) programmer - I've learned it at university, did always a good job in explaining basics to others (also as private coach for not so experienced students). But apart from that, I have trouble to analyze complex code or even write it (seems to go hand in hand with personal organization).
I'm feeling lousy to accept tasks, but not to be able to get a grip in my working environment. After some years, I quit and start over new.

What I'm good at, is tinkering with new and fancy stuff, I think I'm also kind of good in "seeming smart", which comes in handy at job interviews.

One attempt I took was working for a consultancy, which was a big fail for me. After "not fitting" into the next position after that where I got also "quitted" during probation period I was quite happy to get any job (which took me back into my working field as a programmer).

Looking for jobs in the project management direction, most of the time I see that experience is required.

Would it be smart to talk about my current boss about shifting my current job profile or my position inside the company? Should I try get some coaching for myself to at least be better organized and be able to handle more complex tasks which would also benefit me in other roles?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere too true.  Not every worker can be a master of the trade, and not every job requires a master of the trade.

Comment: @joe: a bit of explanation on at least the coaching attempt

Comment: @Anonymous, How are you at the fundamentals? http://leetcode.com or http://binarysearch.com

Comment: It's common for engineers to shift to project management, and I'd definitely ask your employers if that's possible as a long-term goal. Project management does require its own set of skills (people skills, organisation, etc). There may also be alternatives e.g. in sales, testing, or customer support, depending on your skills and interests.

Comment: Have you considered working in Sales positions? Your aptitudes as described could work well with sales - explaining the basics well to others (customers and your internal contacts, for example), catching up on current trends and looking smart

Answer (score 7):

Being a consultant is very different from being a programmer. Being a programmer on a small team is very different from being one on a large team. Many people are good programmers while missing one or more of these skills:

- understanding what people are really asking you to do (especially end users) when they ask for something to be added
- understanding bug reports from end users
- designing large complicated systems that interact with other systems
- carefully and completely making complicated changes in many places and not forgetting any
- writing documentation that is actually useful (eg not: efficiency: this is the efficiency of the component)
- tracking down bugs and understanding what causes them
- estimating how long a set of changes will take and how close they are to done at any point
- communicating with managers, users and so on, especially about dates and deadlines
- choosing function names, variable names and the like that communicate your intent to those who read the code later, and writing good comments
- writing functions that are not too long and not too short, and classes that are not too large and not too small

I could probably list dozens more. How can someone be a good programmer and not be good at one or more of those things? Usually, because they're on a team where someone else does those things for them. (Sometimes, because they are on a team that has accepted their documentation is useless or their code is very hard to maintain or whatever.) If you are clear about what you're good at and what you're not good at, you might be able to find a team where someone else does the things you can't, and you shine at the things you can. Or you may be able to get training or coaching to improve your specific weakness. Some things just take time: architecting big complicated systems and co-ordinating the interactions of several teams and systems is not a task most people can do in their first few years in the industry.

If you are routinely asked to do things you're not good at, and you're about ready to quit over that and just take a semi-random job that may also have parts you're not good at, then it seems there is little risk in discussing this with your boss. The boss may say "sure, X can repro bugs for you and you can fix them once X has established precisely what the bug is" or "sure, Y can do the database parts for you." Or they may say "actually none of us are great at A, B, and C but we muddle along and it works out. Don't worry, you're doing fine and you'll get better." Alas, they may say "you were hired to D, E, and F and if you can't do that, you need to find another job" so be ready if that happens.

Also, you sound a little demotivated and depressed. The issue may not be your skills, but your mood or even health. Changing jobs won't fix that unless something else about this job is demotivating you.

Answer (score -7):

> Would it be smart to talk about my current boss about shifting my current job profile or my position inside the company

No, it would be ridiculous.  Work hard and do your best to build a few years behind you in your current role.

(The idea of being "a consultant" is whacky, you're 20 years from that.)

Enjoy your role, take the pay, live a good life and advance.

Comment: The question said working for a consultancy, not being a consultant. Many consultants also provide software design, development, engineering, management, testing, etc, capabilities for hire. And it's certainly possible to provide consultancy services within a consultancy firm with far less than 20 years experience - setting up your own firm requires maybe 20 years experience but they didn't mention that.